# Creating a presigned url to authenticate users

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react app that has a traditional login page and flow. Once the user enters correct credentials, they are given a jwt which is stored in the browser local storage.

However, I'd like to grant access to certain users by creating a short-term pre-signed URL (same as S3 does). The URL would look like `myapp.com/resource?token=ey6347fdefd....`

I can then add a new route to my app `<Route exact path="/resource" component={Resource}>`. When anyone hits this path, I can define some logic in the `Resource` component to:

1. Extract `token` from query string.
2. Validate `token` and ensure it's not expired using `exp` from token.
3. If successful, render the UI else redirect to `/login`.

Just want to confirm if this is the right approach.

Also, would there be any case if I redirect users to `/login` in step 3 above? Asking because I will be the person creating those pre-signed URLs so assuming it's always correct (?). If a third party created those pre-signed URLs, then I'd be more concerned about validating them.

Comment: If you're including the JWT in the URL, then it's not a short-term URL -- or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I can include the `exp` parameter in the token to auto-invalidate itself after X minutes.